# Equivalent of NORMDIST function in Excel using PL/SQL

Tags: excel, oracle, plsql, statistics

Is there a way to write a stored procedure in PL/SQL to calculate Cumulative Normal Distribution for a given value of x, standard deviation and mean?

There is a formula in excel that does this and it is `NORM.DIST(X, MEAN , STD DEV ,TRUE)`.

I need to do this in PL SQL in oracle or VBA but can do it in other languages too.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
--This stored procedure gives the same result as NORMDIST Function in excel
--The parameters that need to passed are x,mean and standard deviation.
--This method gives the same result as when you pass Cumulative=TRUE in excel.

create or replace FUNCTION NORMSDIST(x_value number,mean_value number,stddev_value number)
RETURN NUMBER IS

        x number;
        t number;
        z number;
        ans number;

BEGIN
  IF (stddev_value = 0) THEN
  RETURN 1;
  END IF;

  x := (x_value-mean_value)/stddev_value;

  z := abs(x)/SQRT(2);

  t := 1.0/(1.0+0.5*z);

  ans := t*exp(-z*z-1.26551223+t*(1.00002368+t*(0.37409196+t*(0.09678418+t*(-0.18628806+t*(0.27886807+t*(-1.13520398+t*(1.48851587+t*(-0.82215223+t*0.17087277)))))))))/2.0;

     If (x <= 0)   
     Then RETURN ans;
     Else return  1-ans;
    End if; 



END NORMSDIST;
```